# RethinkDB: How can I perform sum of 2 columns and divide it in one query and also without mapping?

Tags: jquery, division, rethinkdb

I want to perform this and get the divided result as output, but I get an error.

I have tried this RethinkDB query:

```
r.object(
    "total_page_loads",
    r.table("test_db")("page_loads").sum(),
  "total_clicks",
    r.table("test_db")("clicks").sum(),
  'aggre',
  r.expr('total_page_loads').div('total_clicks')
)
```

Comment: Fixed spelling in title and body

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get the two counts first, and to divide in a seperate step. You can use `.merge` for this:

```
r.expr({
    total_page_loads: r.table('test_db')('page_loads').sum(),
    total_clicks:     r.table('test_db')('clicks').sum()
}).merge({
    aggre: r.row('total_page_loads').div(r.row('total_clicks'))
})
```

Note that:

- You can not refer to fields by only their name as a string. They must be wrapped in an `r.row` inside a command that maps over the table such as `merge`.
- You can use an object literal (wrapped in `r.expr`) instead of `r.object`

Comment: how can i implement it if i also want to implement "filter" for certain amount of time... i mean combine 2 query at the same time like ....